# JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized)

Tags: javascript, function, variables, initialization, undefined

Which method of checking if a variable has been initialized is better/correct?
(Assuming the variable could hold anything (string, int, object, function, etc.))

```
if (elem) { // or !elem
```

or

```
if (typeof elem !== 'undefined') {
```

or

```
if (elem != null) {
```

Comment: if you want to know whether `foo` is declared, either `typeof foo === 'undefined'` or `typeof foo === typeof undefined`

Comment: The highly upvoted answers don't work for variables that are declared but have the value `undefined`. The correct answer is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36432729/772035

Comment: @Paulpro, the version using `hasOwnProperty('bar')` doesn't have the same deficiencies as the others, but would require some adjustment for Node (replace `window` with `global`).

Comment: @Paulpro Indeed, but as I was pondering that before you replied, I came to the conclusion that it's not really a practical problem. When you are dealing with  block or function scoped variables, it's usually code you own or have write access to, so you'll have a runtime error in any case which is fixable. Whereas the usual problem with variables that has not beed defined (doesn't exist) usually lies in code outside of your control, so you need a way of detecting it. So it's the 80/20 solution.

Comment: @Paul that's not the best answer.   You compare to Undefined (without quotes).  It's checking the stored value if you use quotes, and checks if you've ever declared it at all if you don't use them.  See the actual correct answer below, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63459003/9008140

Answer (score 1113, accepted):

The `typeof` operator will check if the variable is really undefined.

```
if (typeof variable === 'undefined') {
    // variable is undefined
}
```

The `typeof` operator, unlike the other operators, doesn't throw a *ReferenceError* exception when used with an undeclared variable.

However, do note that `typeof null` will return `"object"`. We have to be careful to avoid the mistake of initializing a variable to `null`. To be safe, this is what we could use instead:

```
if (typeof variable === 'undefined' || variable === null) {
    // variable is undefined or null
}
```

---

For more info on using strict comparison `===` instead of simple equality `==`, see:
[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/584192)

Comment: Warning: This does not work for members of objects, if you try to access them using the dot notation as in `some_object.a_member`.

Comment: this doesn't check if a variable exists, it checks its value type. You want to check if a variable it's been declared. @BrianKelley's answer is the right one.

Comment: why not just `variable != null` it seems to catch "undefined" variables just as well

Comment: If you wanted to catch if a variable was uninitialized or null, couldn't you use simple equality? ie: `if (typeof variable == 'undefined')`

Answer (score 3907):

You want [the `typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator). Specifically:

```
if (typeof variable !== 'undefined') {
    // the variable is defined
}
```

Comment: This looks a good solution, but can you explain why this works?

Comment: Actually, you should check that the object is what you need it to be. So that would be if( typeof console == 'object' ) { // variable is what I need it to be }

Comment: @George IV: "just do `if( variable ) " -- um, no, that fails for false and 0.

Comment: 'if( variable )' also fails for testing for the existence of object properties.

Comment: @staticsan: That's a good thing to consider, but many times you really only care if it's defined. E.g. an API you're using defines a variable that you're using only to check if the API is loaded.

Comment: "if (typeof variable !== 'undefined') { // variable is not undefined }"  is working for me too... thanks!

Comment: IE8 reported and error when I used: (typeof variable === "undefined" ), so I had to check for (typeof variable === "object" ) and that workded

Comment: @anyone Why is this preferable to `if (variable === undefined) {}` ?

Comment: See a couple answers further down. The value `undefined` is mutable.

Comment: Heads-up: your answer has been migrated here from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript

Comment: As simple of JavaScript as this is I have NEVER used it but it serves my purpose beautifully. I have multiple .js files that run the same functions from a global js file, but only if a certain variable exists should certain functions run. Otherwise what I was doing is setting the variable to true or false and checking for that, but that would require me to address it on dozens of js files, so I needed another solution. Perfect!

Comment: @Jason S "um, no, that fails for false and 0" -- um, yes, if you know that your variable cannot be false or 0 :)

Comment: `typeof null; //=> "object"`

Comment: If you're on ES6 and your variable could be a const or let declared variable, there's a chance this code could fall in the temporal dead zone and throw ReferenceError.
`if (typeof variable !== 'undefined') {
    // the variable is defined
}; 
const variable = 'a';`  => ReferenceError

Comment: This won't work with `let` or `const`. [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-not-hoisted-in-es6)

Comment: Why does it not work with `typeof variable !== undefined` where the apostrophes is removed. Isn't `window.undefined = 'undefined'`?

Comment: This answer doesn't work. This is the only answer here that works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36432729/772035

Comment: you can use !!ArrayName. This will return false if array is undefined or null. In case of empty array it will return true.

Answer (score 341):

In many cases, using:

```
if (elem) { // or !elem
```

will do the job for you!... this will check these below cases:

1. **undefined**: if the value is not defined and it's `undefined`
2. **null**: if it's null, for example, if a DOM element not exists...
3. **empty string**: `''`
4. **0**: number zero
5. **NaN**: not a number
6. **false**

So it will cover off kind of all cases, but there are always weird cases which we'd like to cover as well, for example, a string with spaces, like this `'    '` one, this will be defined in javascript as it has spaces inside string... for example in this case you add one more check using trim(), like:

```
if(elem) {

if(typeof elem === 'string' && elem.trim()) {
///
```

Also, these checks are for **values** only, as objects and arrays work differently in Javascript, empty array `[]` and empty object `{}` are always **true**.

I create the image below to show a quick brief of the answer:

[image: undefined, null, etc]

Comment: Is the first case suitable when checking for an empty array too?

Comment: @ThiagoYoithi, yes, you need to pass Array.length in this case which is 0 when it's empty, like if (myArray.length) {...}

Comment: Yeah, but I would like to know the behavior in this approach: let arrayVar = [];  if(arrayVar) // Is the result of this condition true, or false?

Comment: @ThiagoYoithi in Javascript empty array [] is true, also empty object {}... because they are not values like 0, null, undefined etc... These are check for values... anyway good point to add it to my answer....

Comment: @Alireza, nice! Your answer will help a lot of people out there. I already memorized these falsy values, the only thing that I wasn't sure was about [].

Comment: Regarding the "check me please": This is correct because null and undefined are both "faulty" primitive types. They both represent "nothing" aka "void", so nothing != void is false

Comment: I get a "ReferenceError: elem is not defined"

Comment: @ropo, it's because you even didn't define the elem to check what it's , if it's your case,  you need to check it with typeof(elem)==="string" which is mentioned already...

Comment: Then the answer is misleading when it says `if(elem)` checks for undefined (while it returns not defined error), isn't it?

Comment: Tested the last case it works for undefined and null: https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-lake-4cdfh

Comment: i agree with franky, this answer looks like it would solve ops problem, but it does not have the same effect as the other answers (which is checking if a value exists)

Comment: This is wrong. `bar=undefined` is defined and set to a value. Your answer fails to detect the difference between this and if the variable does not exist.

Comment: Give me a use case for checking if a variable is undefined and if is defined with an undefined value? Some of you are grasping at straws and attempting to look brilliant but if you are setting a value as undefined and checking for that value obviously it will return false or you need to change your code, smh.... this answer is correct!!!!!

Comment: Surprised my the number of upvotes.  The answer is simply wrong.  As mentioned in comments above, "if (elem) {}" does not check for undefined, it will throw an error if the variable is not defined.  However, "if (window.elem) {}" will not throw an error if elem is undefined.

Comment: NOt correct.  Doesn't catch completely undefined variables which is what the OP asked.

Comment: `(someUndefinedVariableName)` fails with `Uncaught ReferenceError: someUndefinedVariableName is not defined`, so I think this answer is wrong.

Comment: very nice description picture 

Answer (score 231):

In JavaScript, a variable can be defined, but hold the value `undefined`, so the most common answer is not technically correct, and instead performs the following:

```
if (typeof v === "undefined") {
   // no variable "v" is defined in the current scope
   // *or* some variable v exists and has been assigned the value undefined
} else {
   // some variable (global or local) "v" is defined in the current scope
   // *and* it contains a value other than undefined
}
```

That may suffice for your purposes.  The following test has simpler semantics, which makes it easier to precisely describe your code's behavior and understand it yourself (if you care about such things):

```
if ("v" in window) {
   // global variable v is defined
} else {
   // global variable v is not defined
}
```

This, of course, assumes you are running in a browser (where `window` is a name for the global object).  But if you're mucking around with globals like this you're probably in a browser.  Subjectively, using `'name' in window` is stylistically consistent with using `window.name` to refer to globals.  Accessing globals as properties of `window` rather than as variables allows you to minimize the number of undeclared variables you reference in your code (for the benefit of linting), and avoids the possibility of your global being shadowed by a local variable.  Also, if globals make your skin crawl you might feel more comfortable touching them only with this relatively long stick.

Comment: This only checks if the variable was declared globally. If you are coding properly, then you are limiting your global vars. It will report false for local vars:  
    (function() { 
        var sdfsfs = 10; 
        console.log( "sdfsfs" in window);
    })()
`

Comment: This is the best f$#^%ing answer. I was at wit's end on this trying to figure out how to account for *exactly* this corner case. Brilliant. Had no idea you could do this.

Comment: Heads-up: your answer has been migrated here from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript

Comment: For Angular users: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be allowed in an ng-if statement.

Comment: ...perfect blueprint for checks along scope. have you any performance indication, if "in window" or "(typeof variable === 'undefined' || variable === null)". Actually I am interested in a hard fact test and not in argumented potential rationale (which I could do myself: second clause has more operations -> worse performance)

Comment: found one: http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/in/. looks like plain (variable === 'undefined') is faster than if-in. I think I write the author of that site to add a test for (typeof variable === 'undefined' || variable === null)

Comment: I don't think (variable === 'undefined') works. If you call a variable which is not declared, wouldn't it throw a ReferenceError? If there is a way to use this technique (property in window) for local scope, it would be great.

Comment: This is a great answer. Local scope does not work, of course, because the `in` is checking for an object property "in" an object, in this case `window`. "Global variables" are those variables who are properties of the window object. To use non-global variables in this way, the `window` in the `"myVariable" in window` statement would have to be replaced with an object, and the local variable would have to be a property of some such object.

Comment: `===` makes no sense here.. result of `typeof` is always string right? `== 'undefined'` is enough

Comment: @l00k yes, both work here, but it makes more sense to rely on strict comparisons wherever possible and just try to treat `==` as nonexistent, as it provides not much besides confusion and error-proneness

Comment: @phil294 yeah I know that philosophy ;) but in my programmer history (more than 10 years) I still think - as far as you know what you are doing "==" is enough.

Comment: This doesn't work for `const` or `let` variables

Comment: `window` might not be defined if the js isn't run in a browser

Comment: `globalThis` (added in ES2020) is a platform-independent mechanism for accessing the global object.

Comment: I think for this edge case (checking if the variable is technically **undeclared**) the best method is to just use a `try ... catch` block, that way you don't need to worry about things like `window` vs. `globalThis` objects, or **global** vs. **local** scopes.

Answer (score 125):

In the majority of cases you would use:

```
elem != null
```

Unlike a simple `if (elem)`, it allows `0`, `false`, `NaN` and `''`, but rejects `null` or `undefined`, making it a good, general test for the presence of an argument, or property of an object.

---

The other checks are not incorrect either, they just have different uses:

- `if (elem)`: can be used if `elem` is guaranteed to be an object, or if `false`, `0`, etc. are considered "default" values (hence equivalent to `undefined` or `null`).
- `typeof elem == 'undefined'` can be used in cases where a specified `null` has a distinct meaning to an uninitialised variable or property.

  - This is the only check that **won't throw an error** if `elem` is not **declared** (i.e. no `var` statement, not a property of `window`, or not a function argument). This is, in my opinion, rather dangerous as it allows typos to slip by unnoticed. To avoid this, see the below method.

---

Also useful is a strict comparison against `undefined`:

```
if (elem === undefined) ...
```

However, because the global `undefined` can be overridden with another value, it is best to declare the variable `undefined` in the current scope before using it:

```
var undefined; // really undefined
if (elem === undefined) ...
```

Or:

```
(function (undefined) {
    if (elem === undefined) ...
})();
```

A secondary advantage of this method is that JS minifiers can reduce the `undefined` variable to a single character, saving you a few bytes every time.

Comment: I'm shocked that you can override `undefined`. I don't even think that's worth mentioning in the answer. Probably the single worst acceptable variable name in all of Javascript.

Comment: This causes an exception and requires you to use `window.` before the variable if used in the global context...this is not the best way.

Comment: Because of this overriding issue you should ALWAYS use `void(0)` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: +1 since this answer points out that sometimes you may actually *want* to identify `false`, `0`, etc. as invalid values.

Answer (score 104):

## Check if [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).[`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)(*"[`varname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)"*)

An alternative to the plethora of `typeof` answers;

[Global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) variables declared with a `var varname = value;` statement in the global scope

> can be accessed as properties of the window object.

As such, the `hasOwnProperty()` method, which

> returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to inheriting it)
>
> can be used to determine whether

a `var` of *"varname"* has been declared globally *i.e.* is a property of the `window`.

```js
// Globally established, therefore, properties of window
var foo = "whatever", // string
    bar = false,      // bool
    baz;              // undefined
//  window.qux does not exist

console.log( [
    window.hasOwnProperty( "foo" ), // true
    window.hasOwnProperty( "bar" ), // true
    window.hasOwnProperty( "baz" ), // true
    window.hasOwnProperty( "qux" )  // false
] );
```

What's great about `hasOwnProperty()` is that in calling it, we don't use a variable that might as yet be undeclared - which of course is half the problem in the first place.

Although not **always** the *perfect* or *ideal* solution, in certain circumstances, it's just the job!

## Notes

**The above is true when using `var` to define a variable**, as opposed to [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) which:

> declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.
>
> is unlike the `var` keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope.
>
> At the top level of programs and functions, `let`, unlike `var`, does not create a property on the global object.

**For completeness:** [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) constants are, by definition, not actually variable (although their content can be); more relevantly:

> Global constants do not become properties of the window object, unlike `var` variables. An initializer for a constant is required; that is, you must specify its value in the same statement in which it's declared.
>
> The value of a constant cannot change through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared.
>
> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned.

Since `let` variables or `const` constants are never properties of any object which has inherited the `hasOwnProperty()` method, it cannot be used to check for their existence.

**Regarding the availability and use of `hasOwnProperty()`:**

> Every object descended from [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) inherits the `hasOwnProperty()` method. [...] unlike the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype chain.

Comment: This an awesome alternative and should be on the top upvoted of this question. Please simplify the answer headline with a working example that returns `true` (e.g. `window.hasOwnProperty('console')` or `var hop = "p";window.hasOwnProperty('hop')`).

Comment: No need to define a function for explaining, people will understand it immediately and a short answer is faster to read. If you still want to leave the snippet, just leave two lines on it, the first defining the var and the second printing the result.

Comment: Finally something that does not throw an error because of accessing a member which does not exist … Something all the `typeof` answers simply overlook.

Comment: This answer is outdated -- per standard ECMAScript you can define variables with `let` where these variables aren't available as properties of the `window` [or any other available] object. `hasOwnProperty` tests for presence of *properties*, not variables and thus cannot be used to detect variables defined by `let`.

Comment: @amn The answer remains true regarding the use of `var` and is in that regard not outdated. I have however added a note outlining how the use of `let` and `const` differs from that of `var`. Thanks for your inspiration; together we rise :)

Comment: Fred, that's an honest effort, thanks. If I were you, I'd put the cherry on top of the cake by mentioning explicitly that variables defined by `let` and `const` (the latter not truly *variable*) are not accessible as properties of any object and therefore the `hasOwnProperty` usage shown in the answer does not apply to these, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @amn It is precisely because it is "obvious" and because there is no implication that `let` (or `const`) variables can be accessed by `hasOwnProperty` that I will leave the answer as is (although I will make a tiny note indicating that I mention `const` only for *completeness* ).

Comment: @amn I have rewritten the answer (hopefully for the last time) to make more clear that `hasOwnProperty` can only be used in the prescribed manner to check for the existence of `var` variables. It reads okay to me.

Comment: Unfortunately not working under IE 11. `hasOwnProperty('indexedDB')` always return `false`, for example even though `indexedDB` does exist

Comment: @yiwen I see that `window.hasOwnProperty("indexedDB")` returns `false` on IE11 while `window.indexedDB` returns the object. On Chrome, the same code returns `true`. IE11 however returns expected results for other checks (e.g. `var foo="foo"; window.hasOwnProperty("foo");` returns `true`), so to say it's "not working" is not quite true. IE11 is clearly just being as temperamental as its ancestors.

Comment: A statement like "something is not working" is either true or false. As long as it fails in one case it qualifies as not working

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I like your method and I think it is very smart way to go. But before we can get rid of IE11 support, I, unfortunately, cannot use this method

Comment: This should be accepted answer. The `typeof` is useless if the variable has not been declared yet.

Answer (score 74):

### How to check if a variable exists

This is a pretty bulletproof solution for testing if a variable exists and has been initialized :

```
var setOrNot = typeof variable !== typeof undefined;
```

It is most commonly used in combination with a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) to set a default in case a certain variable has not been initialized :

```
var dark = typeof darkColor !== typeof undefined ? darkColor : "black";
```

---

### Problems with encapsulation

Unfortunately, you cannot simply encapsulate your check in a function.

You might think of doing something like this :

```
function isset(variable) {
    return typeof variable !== typeof undefined;
}
```

However, this will produce a reference error if you're calling eg. `isset(foo)` and variable `foo` has not been defined, because you cannot pass along a non-existing variable to a function :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined

---

### Testing whether function parameters are undefined

While our `isset` function cannot be used to test whether a variable exists or not (for reasons explained hereabove), it does allow us to test whether the parameters of a function are undefined :

```
var a = '5';

var test = function(x, y) {
    console.log(isset(x));
    console.log(isset(y));
};

test(a);

// OUTPUT :
// ------------
// TRUE
// FALSE
```

Even though no value for `y` is passed along to function `test`, our `isset` function works perfectly in this context, because `y` is known in function `test` as an `undefined` value.

Answer (score 51):

## Try-catch

If variable was not defined at all (for instance: external library which define global variable is not yet loaded - e.g. google maps), you can check this without break code execution using try-catch block as follows (you don't need to `use strict` mode)

```js
try{
  notDefinedVariable;
} catch(e) {
  console.log('detected: variable not exists');
}

console.log('but the code is still executed');

notDefinedVariable; // without try-catch wrapper code stops here

console.log('code execution stops. You will NOT see this message on console');
```

BONUS: (referring to other answers) Why `===` is more clear than `==` ([source](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/))

#### if( a == b )

[image]

#### if( a === b )

[image]

Comment: FYI, (a == b) placed onto Game of Life grid was not all that exciting.

Answer (score 48):

Short way to test a variable is not declared (not undefined) is

```
if (typeof variable === "undefined") {
  ...
}
```

I found it useful for detecting script running outside a browser (not having declared `window` variable).

Comment: is this the "canonical way" that is portable?

Comment: This is wrong. `window.bar=undefined` is defined and set to a value. Your answer fails to detect the difference between this and if the variable does not exist. If you did `this.hasOwnProperty('bar')` it might have worked.

Comment: this code doesn't work and you can verify this by using any browser console

Comment: Consider `const x = 0; (() => console.log(x, this.hasOwnProperty('x')))();`. Variable `x` is defined but false is returned...

Answer (score 43):

There is another short hand way to check this, when you perform simple assignments and related checks. Simply use ***Conditional (Ternary) Operator.***

```
var values = typeof variable !== 'undefined' ? variable : '';
```

Also this will be helpful, when you try to declare the Global variable with instance assignment of the reference variable.

If you wanted to check variable shouldn't be `undefined` or `null`. Then perform below check.

**When the variable is declared, and if you want to check the value, this is even Simple:** *and it would perform `undefined` and `null` checks together.*

```
var values = variable ? variable : '';
```

Comment: the answer as it is flat out wrong.  typeof variable always returns a string, thus is never false. e.g. if `typeof(booooo)` is `"undefined"` then `typeof(typeof boooooo)` is `"string"` and `typeof boooooo && true` is always `true`. @John-Slegers' answer is about as abbreviated as you can get with typeof.

Comment: **Its absolutely correct answer**. [**Here is an working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/o5mzrsfc/1/). And i don't know which scenario you are talking about. The questions is about checking variable existence.

Comment: @mpag Don't Say Flat wrong. **Prove It**. Finding a mistake is real easy, instead you can provide Good answers here!!!. If the answer is flat wrong **28** programmers wouldn't have up-voted without checking my answer. Since there are many reputed answers here they could have up-voted that, not this.

Comment: Actually the second piece of code, is not to check same as above condition. I thought people would understand by this line `If you wanted to check variable shouldn't be undefined or null.`, By this comment, its clearly stating, its not to perform the variable declaration check. that's to check variable value.

Comment: Removed the `typeof`, which was misleading/gives the error. and updated this comment `When the variable is declared, and if you want to check the value, this is even Simple`, I hope this gives the clear answer.

Comment: Thanks for making me correct my answer, Now, clearly we have condition to check JavaScript check if variable exists (is **defined/initialized**), And this answer is not flat out wrong anymore. ;)

Comment: :) quite a bit improved. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "it would perform both checks together" as it's not checking if a variable is declared. It would be assigning a "null" string value if the first variable is declared but not defined.

Comment: your 2nd check will fail with 0 value

Comment: This is wrong. `bar=undefined` is defined and set to a value. Your answer fails to detect the difference between this and if the variable does not exist.

Answer (score 40):

It depends if you just care that the variable has been defined or if you want it to have a meaningful value.

Checking if the type is undefined will check if the variable has been defined yet.

`=== null` or `!== null` will only check if the value of the variable is exactly `null`.

`== null` or `!= null` will check if the value is `undefined` or `null`.

`if(value)` will check if the variable is `undefined`, `null`, `0`, or an empty string.

Answer (score 15):

To check if a variable has been declared/set I did this dirty trick.

I haven't found a way to extract the code to a function, even with `eval`. Se [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized/36432729?noredirect=1#comment116499453_36432729) below for an explanation about why.

```
"use strict";

// var someVar;

var declared;
try {
  someVar;
  declared = true;
} catch(e) {
  declared = false;
}

if (declared) {
  console.log("someVar is declared; now has the value: " + someVar);
} else {
  console.log("someVar is not declared");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "extract the code to a function"?

Comment: @Melab Ideally you could have `function isDefined(x){...}` and then call `isDefined(myVar)`. But there is no way to safely pass a potentially undefined variable to `isDefined` because before the variable can be passed to the function, it must be evaluated, and if it doesn't already exist, then at that point it will throw (outside of the `try/catch` block, which is *in* the function). You have to evaluate the variable directly inside a `try/catch` block, so you cannot wrap the test in a function.

Comment: While this is a good answer technically, it would be evidence of bad design if you truly require this.

Comment: yeah, this is technically correct, but impractically complex to write, when most of the time it doesn't matter if a variable is undeclared vs declared with a value of undefined

Comment: @aross I disagree, if you are writing backwords compatible code- and certain JS implementations don't support things such as `fetch()` so you want to have a fallback

Comment: @AidanWelch I don't understand what `fetch` has to do with anything. If you have code such as `if (foo) { var bar = 123; }` and then you proceed to do stuff with `bar`, you'll need to check whether `bar` exists to begin with. That is bad design which you should solve differently. Either you put the code that does stuff with `bar` in the `if` block, or you initialize `bar` at the top of your function somewhere so it's always defined.

Comment: @aross If it is not a variable you are declaring but instead a standard object that may or may not exist in the environment you need to check if it exists.

Comment: @AidanWelch I think understand what you mean now. But in that case, `typeof` would be sufficient and you don't need the solution in this answer...... This answer is the *only* solution when you can have a variable with value `undefined`. So again, like I said, if you *truly* require this specific solution, that is evidence of bad design.

Comment: @aross No typeof will still error, you need to use a try block

Comment: @AidanWelch I wouldn't know why `typeof` would error. Historically, `typeof` will *always* return a string. It's only recently that it can throw an exception, and that is f.ex. with the `let` keyword, when you try to use the variable before it's defined in the scope. And that doesn't apply in your situation.

Comment: @aross You're right actually, in my code it seemed like there was an error from it, but there must've been some other error, because going back to it now a few days later it does work.

Comment: This is the _only_ correct answer here. I absolutely needed this just now, and could not for the life of me figure out how to test for it. Checking if a variable exists accesses a non-existent variable, which is an error only _some_ of the time, depending on what mode your browser decides to be running your JavaScript in, which you cannot detect from your code. :-/

Comment: @BallpointBen Thanks so much for your explanation. I referred to it in my answer.

Answer (score 12):

The highest answer is correct, use typeof.

However, what I wanted to point out was that in JavaScript `undefined` is mutable (for some ungodly reason). So simply doing a check for `varName !== undefined` has the potential to not always return as you expect it to, because other libs could have changed undefined. A few answers (@skalee's, for one), seem to prefer not using `typeof`, and that could get one into trouble.

The "old" way to handle this was declaring undefined as a var to offset any potential muting/over-riding of `undefined`. However, the best way is still to use `typeof` because it will ignore any overriding of `undefined` from other code. Especially if you are writing code for use in the wild where who knows what else could be running on the page...

Comment: The point is moot, because if varName is undefined then `varName !== undefined` will just cause a ReferenceError. The mutability of `undefined` won't matter.

Comment: Heads-up: your answer has been migrated here from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript

Comment: In newer Javascript versions `undefined` is an read only property. However to be bulletproof you can use `typeof mvVar === typeof void 0`. `void 0` returns `undefined` always.

Answer (score 11):

```
if (typeof console != "undefined") {    
   ...
}
```

Or better

```
if ((typeof console == "object") && (typeof console.profile == "function")) {    
   console.profile(f.constructor);    
}
```

Works in all browsers

Comment: Why the latter is better in your opinion?

Comment: @skalee I agree the latter is better. This for the simple reason that you check if the types are the ones you want before using them.

Comment: Heads-up: your answer has been migrated here from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript

Answer (score 11):

To contribute to the debate, if I know the variable should be a string or an object I always prefer `if (!variable)`, so checking if its falsy. This can bring to more clean code so that, for example:

```js
if (typeof data !== "undefined" && typeof data.url === "undefined") {
    var message = 'Error receiving response';
    if (typeof data.error !== "undefined") {
        message = data.error;
    } else if (typeof data.message !== "undefined") {
        message = data.message;
    }
    alert(message); 
}
```

..could be reduced to:

```js
if (data && !data.url) {
  var message = data.error || data.message || 'Error receiving response';
  alert(message)
}
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked. If data.url is equal to `''` your solution would consider it undefined, when it is in fact defined as containing an empty string.

Comment: I agree is not what has been asked, and you are right: the empty string '' would be considered undefined. But I posted this because I thought it could be useful on the debate that has been created among different answers. And in the example, as well as in many other cases, you just want to print a string if there is actually content, so it's ok to take advantage of the fact the javascript considers falsy both empty string and undefined

Answer (score 9):

In the particular situation outlined in the question,

```
typeof window.console === "undefined"
```

is identical to

```
window.console === undefined
```

I prefer the latter since it's shorter.

Please note that we look up for `console` only in global scope (which is a `window` object in all browsers).  In this particular situation it's desirable.  We don't want `console` defined elsewhere.

@BrianKelley in his great answer explains technical details.  I've only added lacking conclusion and digested it into something easier to read.

Comment: Heads-up: your answer has been migrated here from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript

Comment: False.  the latter throws an exception in my console.

Comment: HOW?  show the stack trace.  There's no way that is throwing an exception.  Window is never null.

Answer (score 9):

The most robust 'is it defined' check is with **typeof**

```
if (typeof elem === 'undefined')
```

If you are just checking for a defined variable to assign a default, for an easy to read one liner
you can often do this:

```
elem = elem || defaultElem;
```

It's often fine to use, see: [Idiomatic way to set default value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505840/idiomatic-way-to-set-default-value-in-javascript)

There is also this one liner using the **typeof** keyword:

```
elem = (typeof elem === 'undefined') ? defaultElem : elem;
```

Answer (score 9):

Null is a value in JavaScript and `typeof null` returns `"object"`

Therefore, accepted answer will not work if you pass null values. If you pass null values, you need to add an extra check for null values:

```
if ((typeof variable !== "undefined") && (variable !== null))  
{
   // the variable is defined and not null
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It is difficult to distinguish between undefined and null. **Null** is a value you can assign to a variable when you want to indicate that the variable has no particular value. **Undefined**
is a special value which will be the default value of unassigned variables.

```
var _undefined;
var _null = null;

alert(_undefined); 
alert(_null); 
alert(_undefined == _null);
alert(_undefined === _null);
```

Comment: Would be helpful to show inline the output of each alert.

Comment: @demisx Agreed, but instead of suggesting the edit, why not just make it? The option is there for a reason. Some may consider it rude; I consider it efficient - so edited the answer myself (pending review).

Comment: @Fred - I looked at the edit history and can guess why your edits were rejected...  rather than just adding lines to show what the output would be, as demisx suggested, you significantly changed what Jith had posted.

Answer (score 8):

you can use the `typeof` operator.

For example,

```
var dataSet;

alert("Variable dataSet is : " + typeof dataSet);
```

Above code snippet will return the output like

> variable dataSet is : undefined.

Comment: Heads-up: your answer has been migrated here from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript

Answer (score 8):

I use two different ways depending on the object.

```
if( !variable ){
  // variable is either
  // 1. '';
  // 2. 0;
  // 3. undefined;
  // 4. null;
  // 5. false;
}
```

Sometimes I do not want to evaluate an empty string as falsey, so then I use this case

```
function invalid( item ){
  return (item === undefined || item === null);
}

if( invalid( variable )){
  // only here if null or undefined;
}
```

If you need the opposite, then in the first instance !variable becomes !!variable, and in the invalid function === become != and the function names changes to notInvalid.

Answer (score 5):

My preference is `typeof(elem) != 'undefined' && elem != null`.

However you choose, consider putting the check in a function like so

```
function existy (x) {
    return typeof (x) != 'undefined' && x != null;
}
```

If you don't know the variable is declared then continue with `typeof (x) != 'undefined' && x != null;`

Where you know the variable is declared but may not be existy, you could use

```
existy(elem) && doSomething(elem);
```

The variable you are checking may be a nested property sometimes. You can use prop || {} to go down the line checking existance to the property in question:

```
var exists = ((((existy(myObj).prop1||{}).prop2||{}).prop3||{})[1]||{}).prop4;
```

After each property use (...' || {}').nextProp so that a missing property won't throw an error.

Or you could use existy like `existy(o) && existy(o.p) && existy(o.p.q) && doSomething(o.p.q)`

Comment: If you put it in a function, it’s redundant. `typeof (x) != 'undefined' && x != null` is equivalent to `x != null` when `x` is declared.

Answer (score 5):

These answers (aside from the Fred Gandt solution ) are all either incorrect or incomplete.

Suppose I need my `variableName;` to carry an `undefined` value, and therefore it has been declared in a manner such as `var variableName;` which means it's already **initialized**; - How do I check if it's already declared?

Or even better - how do I immediately check if "Book1.chapter22.paragraph37" exists with a single call, but not rise a reference error?

We do it by using the most powerful JasvaScript operator, the **in** operator.:

```
"[variable||property]" in [context||root] 
>> true||false
```

Comment: if ( ("url" in req.body)  == false && req.body.url.length > 1

Comment: This is not true for variables declared with `let` and `const` instead of `var`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: @catwith, thanks for your input however you should take into account when publicly commenting, that analogous things are not the same thing. A *var* is a variable; a *let* is a proposition; and a *const* is the exact opposite and antinomy of var's. That solution is written to exactly address the question in its explicit request. Thanks!

Comment: could you explain "a let is a proposition"?   In fact, could you perhaps explain why W3Schools calls all three of them variables with different levels of restriction?  Example:  Var declares a variable.  Let declares a variable with scope.  Const declares a variable with scope and prevents re-assignment.  How do you think they are somehow completely different things, when the creators of the script (oracle) say they aren't?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the situation. If you're checking for something that may or may not have been defined globally outside your code (like jQuery perhaps) you want:

```
if (typeof(jQuery) != "undefined")
```

(No need for strict equality there, typeof always returns a string.) But if you have arguments to a function that may or may not have been passed, they'll always be defined, but null if omitted.

```
function sayHello(name) {
    if (name) return "Hello, " + name;
    else return "Hello unknown person";
}
sayHello(); // => "Hello unknown person"
```

Comment: I agree here. I don't know why everyone is using strict equality when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a try...catch block like the following:

```js
var status = 'Variable exists'

try {
  myVar
} catch (ReferenceError) {
  status = 'Variable does not exist'
}

console.log(status)
```

A disadvantage is you cannot put it in a function as it would throw a ReferenceError

```js
function variableExists(x) {
  var status = true
  try {
    x
  } catch (ReferenceError) {
    status = false
  }
  
  return status
}

console.log(variableExists(x))
```

**Edit:**

If you were working in front-end Javascript and you needed to check if a variable was not initialized (`var x = undefined` would count as not initialized), you could use:

```js
function globalVariableExists(variable) {
  if (window[variable] != undefined) {
    return true
  }
  
  return false
}

var x = undefined

console.log(globalVariableExists("x"))

console.log(globalVariableExists("y"))

var z = 123

console.log(globalVariableExists("z"))
```

**Edit 2:**

If you needed to check if a variable existed in the current scope, you could simply pass `this` to the function, along with the name of the variable contained in a string:

```js
function variableExists(variable, thisObj) {
  if (thisObj[variable] !== undefined) {
    return true
  }
  
  return false
}

class someClass {
  constructor(name) { 
    this.x = 99
    this.y = 99
    this.z = 99
    this.v = 99
    
    console.log(variableExists(name, this))
  }
}

new someClass('x')
new someClass('y')
new someClass('z')
new someClass('v')
new someClass('doesNotExist')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if (variable === undefined) {}
```

works just fine, and only checks for undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted something similar: A function to check if a variable had a `useful` value, where 0 is useful, but empty strings, arrays, and objects are not (for my application). Based on the various answers and comments, I came up with the `isSet()` function defined and tested below; it returns `true` for the first half of the test values and `false` for the second, which is what I wanted and needed:

```
let fn = [1234, "1234", 0, "0", [1,2], {name: "number"}, "", [], {}, null, NaN, undefined]

console.log(fn)
const isSet = (val) => {
    switch (typeof val) {
        case 'number': return !isNaN(val); break; // as long as it is a number other than NaN....
        case 'string': return val.length > 0; break;
        case 'undefined': return false; break;
        case 'object':
            if (val === null) return false;
            else return Object.keys(val).length > 0;
            break;
    }
}

for (index in fn) {
    const item = fn[index];
    console.log(`ind: ${index}; ${typeof item}; ${isSet(item)}`)
}
```

Results (under `node v16.16.0`):

```
[
  1234,
  '1234',
  0,
  '0',
  [ 1, 2 ],
  { name: 'number' },
  '',
  [],
  {},
  null,
  NaN,
  undefined
]
ind: 0; number; true
ind: 1; string; true
ind: 2; number; true
ind: 3; string; true
ind: 4; object; true
ind: 5; object; true
ind: 6; string; false
ind: 7; object; false
ind: 8; object; false
ind: 9; object; false
ind: 10; number; false
ind: 11; undefined; false
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised this wasn't mentioned yet...

here are a couple of additional variations using `this['var_name']`

the benefit of using this method that it can be used before a variable is defined.

```js
if (this['elem']) {...}; // less safe than the res but works as long as you're note expecting a falsy value
if (this['elem'] !== undefined) {...}; // check if it's been declared
if (this['elem'] !== undefined && elem !== null) {...}; // check if it's not null, you can use just elem for the second part

// these will work even if you have an improper variable definition declared here
elem = null; // <-- no var here!! BAD!
```

Comment: This is wrong. `window.bar=undefined` is defined and set to a value. Your answer fails to detect the difference between this and if the variable does not exist. If you did `this.hasOwnProperty('bar')` it might have worked.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this method for it's accuracy and succinctness:

```js
var x
if (x === void 0) {
  console.log(`x is undefined`)
} else {
  console.log(`x is defined`)
}
```

As has been mentioned in other comments and answers, `undefined` isn't guaranteed to be undefined. Because it's not a keyword, it can be redefined as a variable in scopes other than the global scope. Here's little example that demonstrates this nuance:

```js
var undefined = 'bar'
console.log(`In the global scope: ${undefined}`)

function foo() {
  var undefined = 'defined'
  var x
  if (x === undefined) {
    console.log(`x === undefined`)
  } else {
    console.log(`x !== undefined`)
  }
  if (x === void 0) {
    console.log(`x === void 0`)
  } else {
    console.log(`x !== void 0`)
  }
}

foo()
```

See [void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) for compatibility (supported in IE5!?!! Wow!).

Comment: Does this have any advantage over `typeof x === 'undefined'`? Redefining `undefined` doesn't affect that does it?

Comment: I don't think redefining `undefined` as any affect on `typeof x === 'undefined'`, since you're not actually referencing the `undefined` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

In ***ReactJS***, things are a bit more complicated!  This is because it is a compiled environment, which follows [ESLint's `no-undef`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define) rule since [`react-scripts@2.0.3`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/) (released [Oct. 1st, 2018)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts/v/2.0.3).  The documentation here is helpful to anyone interested in this problem...

> In JavaScript, prior to ES6, variable and function declarations are hoisted to the top of a scope, so it's possible to use identifiers before their formal declarations in code....
>
> This [new] rule [of ES6] will warn when it encounters a reference to an identifier that has not yet been declared.

So, while it's possible to have an `undefined` (or "uninitialized") variable, it is *not possible* to have an undeclared variable in ReactJS without turning off the eslint rules.

This can be very frustrating -- there are so many projects on GitHub that simply take advantage of the pre-ES6 standards; and directly compiling these without any adjustments is basically impossible.

*But, for ReactJS,* you can use `eval()`.  If you have an undeclared variable like...

```
if(undeclaredvar) {...}
```

You can simply rewrite this part as...

```
if(eval('typeof undeclaredvar !== "undefined"')) {...}
```

For instance...

```js
if(eval("false")) {
  console.log("NO!");
}
if(eval("true")) {
  console.log("YEAH!");
}
```

For those importing GitHub repositories into a ReactJS project, this is simply the only way to check if a variable is declared.  Before closing, I'd like to remind you that [there are security issues with `eval()` if use incorrectly](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/94020).

Answer (score 0):

For the `if` condition to work correctly, we have to use the keyword `let` for creating variables.

```
let name = undefined; 
if (name) { 
    alert('valid')
};
```