# How do I test if a variable in Javascript is initialized?

Tags: javascript

How do I test if a variable in my javascript code is initialized?

This test should return false for

```
var foo;
```

and true for

```
var foo = 5;
```

Comment: if `(foo == null)?` or do you need to handle the case that it has been initialized to null?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript check if variable exists - Which method is better?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-which-method-is-better)

Comment: actually, yes, i do need to differentiate from null thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if (foo === undefined) { /* not initialized */ }
```

or for the paranoid

```
if (foo === (void) 0)
```

This is the sort of thing that you can test right in your JavaScript console.  Just declare a variable and then use it in (well, *as*) an expression. What the console prints is a good hint to what you need to do.

Answer (score 7):

Using the typeof operator you can use the following test:

```
if (typeof foo !== 'undefined') {
    // foo has been set to 5
}
else {
    // foo has not been set
}
```

I find the jQuery fundamentals [JavaScript Basics](http://jqfundamentals.com/#chapter-2) chapter really useful.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This works for functions as well. Comparing a non-initialized function with null (as in the answer) will throw an exception.