# How to check if a JavaScript variable is NOT undefined?

Tags: javascript, undefined

Things I’ve tried that don’t seem to work:

```
if(lastName != "undefined")
```

```
if(lastName != undefined)
```

```
if(undefined != lastName)
```

Comment: `if(lastName != undefined)` This didn't work? Are you getting a *ReferenceError* in the console? If so, instead of avoiding the error by using `typeof` *(as Crockford followers will suggest)*, you should be declaring your variables properly.

Comment: if "if(typeof lastName !== "undefined")" is not working for you, you may want to check your code for other problems

Comment: Any of the last three will work if you're coding properly. Your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Why not simply inverse working condition ?? if(!(lastName === undefined)) It is true for null and false for undefined.

Answer (score 529, accepted):

```
var lastname = "Hi";

if(typeof lastname !== "undefined")
{
  alert("Hi. Variable is defined.");
}
```

Comment: Can't we just check it with if(lastname)... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Jordan No - because there are other values `lastname` could take which would also match that condition - e.g. `0`, `null`, `''` (empty string). These are called "falsy" values.

Comment: @almcaffee a falsey value is not the same as undefined

Comment: more secure code is:

if (lastname && typeof lastname !== "undefined"){

alert("Hi. Variable is defined.");

}

  checking if 'lastname 'and is also not 'undefined'