# variable check (extension of discussion 5113374)

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-assignment

[This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-which-method-is-better) was interesting but I have not been able to find something that's really going to work for me as I really just want to return `true` or `false` on an object's existence. I also really dislike verbose code and am looking for a simple and easy way to write things with minimum fuss.

For example it's suposed to be defined like this: `Bigobject.option` but that may not yet exist.

So I came up with this:

`(!Bigobject.option == false)`, and this returns `false` if `option` isn't yet in existence, and `true` if it has been set to anything, including "nothing" or an empty string, object or array.

### What I'd like to understand:

Is this a weird way to do it? Is it "legal"? Is this going to work consistently? Am I supposed to do it differently? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it's about readability right after functionality.

`(!Bigobject.option == false)` is confusing to read in something that you haven't been working on.  Try to read your code as someone whose never seen your code before.  Can you predict what `(!Bigobject.option == false)` will return immediately?

I agree with the selected answer in the linked question, because you will (probably) know what `(Bigobject.option === null)` as a new reader.

To do what you are asking: return a bool of a variable's existence.  I would use `(typeof(Bigobject.option) === "undefined")` unless it's possible for `Bigobject.option` to be the string `"undefined"`

Edit: I realized I didn't really answer your questions...

**Is this a weird way to do it? Is it "legal"?**

- IMO it's weird but I'm pretty sure it's legal. jslint would warn you about "==".

**Is this going to work consistently?**

- If Bigobject.option = false it will return false.

**Am I supposed to do it differently?**

- I suggest you do.

Comment: thanks for the write-up. in fact, theoretically it's possible for Bigobject.option to be the actual string "undefined", so I'm a bit worried about it. And what's wrong with "=="?

Comment: Definitely use the null way in your situation.  There's nothing wrong with "==", it just does type coercion before comparing, which might be convenient, but you have to be aware of what's being compared. http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#eqeq