# Is there a shorter way to test if a variable has been declared and is not null?

Tags: javascript

I understand why you would want to test for both null and undefined in javascript:

```
var declared;
...
if ('undefined' !== typeof declared && null !== declared) {
    // do something with declared
}
```

or

```
function doSomethingWithDefined(defined) {
    if ('undefined' !== typeof declared && null !== declared) {
        // do something with declared
    }
}
```

Is there a way to shorten this statement? It's pretty verbose pattern.

Comment: Wrap it in your own function? Also, have you read [this post?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized-which-method-is-b)

Comment: @Dave If `var == 0`, then `!var` is true.

Comment: In the title you state that you want to test whether a variable is declared. In the actual question you want to test whether a variable is `undefined` or `null`. What is it now? A variable is declared when it is defined with `var foo` somewhere. `undefined` and `null` are values an existing variable can have. Depending on what you want, the code can be shortened or not.

Comment: Good point, Felix. I'll clarify the title.

Comment: Still not 100% clear to me (regarding the content of the question). Does this mean that `declared` might not exist? Or does it always exist and you just want to test whether it has a value other than `undefined` and `null`?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no single solution that fits all use cases.

Comment: I see the nature of your question now, Felix. I'm assuming that `declared` exists in the current scope.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at CoffeeScript, the language which addresses specifically such shortcomings in JavaScript. Regarding your question it has `?` postfix operator which can be used like this: `if var? then 'ok' else 'nope'`

Comment: In that case `variable != null` will be `true` if `variable` is either `null` or `undefined`. The `typeof` test is only necessary if you are not sure whether the variable exists.

Comment: Why not test that `declared` is what you expect instead? For example `if (typeof declared === "string")`

Comment: @andreypopp, and in coffeescript `a?` compiles to `typeof a !== "undefined" && a !== null`.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5113374/218196.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand exactly!

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand besides that `a?()` compiles to `if (typeof a === "function") { a(); }` and `a?.b` compiles to `if (typeof a !== "undefined" && a !== null) {  a.b; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define a variable like this:

```
var defined;
```

It has no value, but you don't get a ReferenceError, because the reference exists.  It just doesn't reference anything.  Thus, the following is valid.

```
if (defined != null) { ... }
```

In the case of a function, such as this

```
function doSomethingWithDefined(defined) {
    if (defined != null) { ... }
}
```

It can be translated to:

```
function doSomethingWithDefined() {
    var defined = arguments[0];
    if (defined != null) { ... }
}
```

Because the variable is declared implicitly (but not necessarily defined), you can do this and not get an exception, so there's no need for `typeof`.

```
doSomethingWithDefined("value"); // passes defined != null
doSomethingWithDefined(); // defined == null, but no exception is thrown
```

---

The typeof operator is usually used when you're not sure if a variable has been declared.  However there is an alternative that works for all real world scenarios.

```
if (window.myvariable != null) {
    // do something
}
```

Because global variables are the only non-parameter variables you should be concerned about, using property access we can also avoid the exception.

---

That said, I strongly recommend type checking, rather than type avoiding.  Be positive!

**Is it a string?**

```
if (typeof declared === "string"){ ... }
```

**Is it an array?**

```
if (typeof declared === "object" && declared.length != null){ ... }
```

**Is it a non-array object?**

```
if (typeof declared === "object" && declared.length == null){ ... }
```

**Is it a function?**

```
if (typeof declared === "function"){ ... }
```

Comment: Please provide a case where a non-global, non-parameter variable *may* or *may not* be defined.  I can't think of any, but I've been wrong before :-)

Comment: I've never considered positive typeof tests before, which makes a lot of sense. I guess I haven't written enough javascript yet ;) I'm going to think about this some more, but this might be the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: What's the point of the first two examples? `arguments` has nothing to do with the question and is probably rather confusing than helping.

Comment: It shows why you don't need to be extra safe and use the typeof operator inside a function.  The two are equivalent code.  I find that explaining internals dissolves some of the mystery.  I'll try to clarify it, though.