# IF null ELSE - Correct syntax of If Else

Tags: javascript

I want to check if my json data is null/undefined. I have the following code but it seems to skip the checking and go straight to the `else`.

```
if (events === null) {
    container.append(nano(nogig));
} else {
    events[0].start.good_date = good_date(events[0].start.date);
    container.append(nano(template, events[0]));
}
```

Line 385 on this JSfiddle

**http://jsfiddle.net/5WQxq/**

Comment: why are you using === rather than ==?

Comment: @Kritner: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) to understand why.

Comment: right, but how can the type of a "null" ever be equivalent to (events)null without some sort of conversion being done on events?  With the === operator your objects are compared as is yes?  As the boolean said that should get you the expected results.  Also read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized-which-method-is-b i think it touches on pretty much the same issue you've hit

Comment: @djikay: The `==` is the correct solution if he wants to check for both `null` and `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (!events) {
            container.append(nano(nogig));
        } else {
            events[0].start.good_date = good_date(events[0].start.date);
            container.append(nano(template, events[0]));
        }
```

This checks for null and undefined.

Comment: And for `0`, `false`, `NaN` and `''`.

Comment: If you only want to match `null` and `undefined`, the condition should be something like `events === null || events === undefined`

Comment: If the OP only wants to match `null` and `undefined` they could use `== null` rather than `=== null`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `==` operator rather than the `===` operator then testing against `null` will also match on `undefined`. That is `undefined == null` will return `true`, while `undefined === null` will return `false`. So try this:

```
if (events == null) {
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5WQxq/1/

Alternatively you can explicitly test for both values:

```
if (events === null || events === undefined) {
```

Or you can just test for a falsy value:

```
if (!events) {
```

(...which would also match on `false`, `0`, empty string, and `NaN`, but those values aren't likely to apply and in any case if they did occur you'd still want the `if` case to match.)