# Javascript and Angular undefined variables determination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined

I'm trying to understand better how to determine if a variable is undefined and I get mixed results, hopfuly someone can make it clearer.

This is the example:

[image]

What I expect is none_exisiting_variable to result 'false' for the isDefined check.

Comment: Related: [JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized-which-method-is-b)

Comment: Hey thanks, I came across this post but wanted to discover if there is an angular way to overcome this

Answer (score 1):

That's the difference between

1. an `undefined` value, or a variable whose value is `undefined` (that's what can check `angular.isDefined`)
2. an undefined variable : any reference to its name is a reference error

To check a variable is not defined, do

```
if (typeof myvariable === "undefined") {
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I check if the variable is undefined? (your second scenario)

Comment: With a `try`...`catch`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = 'foo';
angular.isDefined(foo) // true;
angular.isDefined(bar) // false
var bar = 'bar';
```