# How can I avoid the error when an undefined variable is referred to in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The following throws and error "module is not defined" in a browser. Why and how can I avoid the error given that I cannot be sure ahead of time that module will be defined?

```
;(function() {
    var version = '0.0.1';

    /**
     * This file needs to work in
     * both NodeJS and browsers.
     */
    if (module) {
        module.exports = version;
    } else {
        define(function() {
            return version;
        });
    }
}());
```

Comment: see also [JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized) - Which method is better?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5113374/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in this check to see if `module` has been defined

```
if(typeof module !== "undefined") {
    // do stuff
}
```

In your example, you get an exception because `module` has not been declared or assigned by the time it gets to your condition. So when you try to check if it's null or not by doing `if(module)`, the variable has never been assigned so it throws and exception. Your code would work if right before the condition you did `var module = null`. Even though you set it to `null` it has been assigned, so it's not `undefined`.

Using `typeof` allows the identifier to never have been declared before, and because of that you can avoid the exception you're experiencing.

Comment: Why does that work, and my example does not?

Comment: @BenAston I edited my answer to try and explain the difference.

Comment: But I am not checking for null. I am checking for truthiness. `module` is `undefined` and hence should coerce to `false` surely. I am not in strict mode, so no error should be thrown, no?

Comment: `var foo; if (foo) {...` is different of `if (foo) {...` in the last case you will get the error because there is no `foo` var, or, in your case, the `module` var