# Javascript checking whether a variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, adsense

To check whether adsense script is loaded or not, I use this:

```
var isAdsenseNotLoaded = (typeof adsbygoogle.loaded === 'undefined');
```

But from many users has this error in stack trace:

```
ReferenceError: adsbygoogle is not defined
    at http://example.com/file.js:1:42020
```

So should I also check whether `adsbygoogle` and also `adsbygoogle.loaded` ?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized-which-method-is-b)?

Comment: @Paolo Not quite - tha'ts adressing a single variable, rather than a nested property

Comment: The operation should be applied to all the interested elements. See the answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to check if `adsbygoogle` is defined first:

`var isAdsenseNotLoaded = !adsbygoogle || typeof adsbygoogle.loaded === 'undefined';`

Comment: I suppose first part will be `adsbygoogle == false` or similar thing ? Because I need to check whether adsense is not loaded.

Comment: @trante updated, missed the Not in `isAdsenseNotLoaded`

Comment: This does not work. when adsbygoogle is undefined it doesn't do anything. I tried alert(isAdsenseNotLoaded); only works when the object is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check for `typeof adsbygoogle` first, this will return if the global variable `adsbygoogle` is loaded.

```
var isAdsenseNotLoaded = (typeof adsbygoogle === 'undefined' || typeof adsbygoogle.loaded === 'undefined');
```

Checking for global variables with `typeof` will never produce any exceptions due to trying to access an undefined variable. Reference: [JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized-which-method-is-b)

Comment: This does not work. when adsbygoogle is undefined it doesn't do anything. I tried alert(isAdsenseNotLoaded); only works when the object is defined.

Answer (score 0):

So the whole object is not defined

```
var isAdsenseNotLoaded = (typeof adsbygoogle === 'undefined' || typeof adsbygoogle.loaded === 'undefined');
```

Just check in the first step if the object exists and then if it is loaded.

Comment: This does not work. when adsbygoogle is undefined it doesn't do anything. I tried alert(isAdsenseNotLoaded); only works when the object is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that many people come here because they searched for OP's error message.

Putting `window.` in front of `adsbygoogle` solves the issue, because this way, if `adsbygoogle` doesn't exist yet, it will be created.

```
(window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})
```