# Javascript Syntax - if statement

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

i have the following object:

```
var quarters = {
                q1:false,
                q2:false,
                q3:false,
                q4:{name: "i'm q4"}
                }
```

My question is why the following IF is returning true?

```
if (quarters.q1 == quarters.q2 == quarters.q3 == quarters.q4 == false)
```

How can i ask `if all quarters are false`?

The reason I'm not using `!quarters.q1 && !quarters.q2 && !quarters.q3 && !quarters.q4` is because sometimes, some of the properties are not defined at all.

Comment: `toppingOrder` is `undefined`

Comment: `false == false` is `true`, `true == false` is `false`, `false == false` is `true`... you can figure this out with pen and paper.

Comment: I just fixed the typos

Comment: *"The reason I'm not using !quarters.q1 && !quarters.q2 && !quarters.q3 && !quarters.q4 is because sometimes, some of the properties are not defined at all."* – I don't understand why that's a reason to use `==` or how that fixes that issue.

Comment: @deceze It doesn't. I know i have a mistake, I'm asking how to fix it. I tried to explain what I'm trying to achieve and not How come my code isn't working....

Comment: Well, `!quaters.q1 && !quaters.q2 ...` *should* be what you're looking for. That says *if q1 is falsey and q2 is falsey ...*, which is answering the question *are all quarters falsey?* Whether one quarter is undefined or not actually makes no difference here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> why the following IF is returning true?

Assuming `toppingOrder` is `quarters`, lets fill it in and see what we have

```
if (toppingOrder.q1 == toppingOrder.q2 == toppingOrder.q3 == toppingOrder.q4 == false)
// same as
if (false == false == false == {name: "i'm q4"} == false)
// same as
if ((((false == false) == false) == {name: "i'm q4"}) == false)
// same as
if (((true == false) == {name: "i'm q4"}) == false)
// same as
if ((false == {name: "i'm q4"}) == false)
// same as
if (false == false)
// same as
if (true)
```

> How can i ask if all quarters are false?

You either have to loop, use a *logical AND `&&`* or some *Array* method like `.every`

```
// logical AND `&&`
if (
       false === toppingOrder.q1
    && false === toppingOrder.q2
    && false === toppingOrder.q3
    && false === toppingOrder.q4
    ) // ...

// Array `.every`
if (
    [toppingOrder.q1, toppingOrder.q2, toppingOrder.q3, toppingOrder.q4].every(
            function (e) {return e === false;}
        )
    ) // ...
```

It is actually much easier to test *all `true`*, so consider if you can phrase your `if` like that instead, e.g. using *logical NOT `!`*

```
if (!toppingOrder.q1 && !toppingOrder.q2 && !toppingOrder.q3 && !toppingOrder.q4) // ...
// or
if (
    [!toppingOrder.q1, !toppingOrder.q2, !toppingOrder.q3, !toppingOrder.q4].every(Boolean)
    ) // ...
```

Comment: Nice explanation, That is what i was looking for: Understanding what I'm doing wrong + understanding how to achieve my goal

Comment: @TBE to check if they are defined is [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5113396/1326147): for your case you can simply use `e == null`, but notice that `false == null` or `'' == null` both return `false` and `undefined==null` returns `true`.

Comment: @Armfoot checking for _falsy_ is as easy as logical a not, which is why the last edit added a logical not way. Being _falsy_ is more general than being `false`, which is why I didn't answer with it immediately.

Comment: Paul, I was answering his other comment-question before he edited it out. Btw, you may also want to edit the parenthesis' order in your first block, since the comparison execution is from left to right as [Elentriel mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34045592/1326147). `2==0==0` and `(2==0)==0` both return `true` but `2==(0==0)` returns `false`.

Comment: @Armfoot ah yeah, I'm used to ltr invocation in JavaScript but because it has an `=` in there I was treating it like setters instead, thanks will edit

Answer (score 2):

```
quarters.q1 == quarters.q2 == quarters.q3 == quarters.q4 == false

true == quarters.q3 == quarters.q4 == false

false == quarters.q4 == false

true == false
```

What you are essentially doing is this

everything will execute from left to right, unless you set the order (with `( )`)

you could go this way about it

```
function get_bool(quarters){
 for(k in quarters)
 {
  if(quarters[k] != false)
  {
   return true;
  }
 }
 return false;
}
```