# How to check variable is set and exists from javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

I am getting below json data:

```
{
  "ID": [
    "The i d field is required."
  ],
  "terms_condition": [
    "The terms condition field is required."
  ]
}
```

and stored in variable:

```
var DataJson = data.responseText;
var Json = JSON.parse(DataJson);

var IdError = Json.ID[0];
var TermsConditionError = Json.terms_condition[0];
```

Now I am getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` when `ID` is not `exists`

I have tried with this example to prevent error handling.

```
if (typeof Json.ID[0] !== 'undefined') {
    alert('validation message found');
} else {
    alert('validation message not found');
}
```

but this is not working any idea what i am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: if (Json && Json.ID && typeof...)

Comment: maybe the data is not in time ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether a variable or a field is defined you can compare it with `undefined`

```
if ((Json !== undefined) && (Json.ID !== undefined) && (Json.ID[0] !== undefined)) {
    alert('validation message found');
} else {
    alert('validation message not found');
}
```

I don't see any issue in your code. See the snippet below.

```js
var Json = JSON.parse('{"ID": ["The i d field is required."], "terms_condition": ["The terms condition field is required."]}');

var IdError = Json.ID[0];
var TermsConditionError = Json.terms_condition[0];

document.writeln(IdError + '<br>');
document.writeln(TermsConditionError + '<br>');
document.writeln('==================<br>');

function isDefined(Json) {
  return (Json !== undefined) && (Json.ID !== undefined) && (Json.ID[0] !== undefined);
}
  
var inputData = [
  undefined,
  {},
  {ID: ''},
  {ID: ['value']}
];

inputData.forEach(function(inputDaten) {
  document.writeln(JSON.stringify(inputDaten) + ': ' + isDefined(inputDaten) + '<br>');
});
```

Probably the issue is with `data.responseText`

Comment: Hi I have tried you example but every time I am getting `alert('validation message found')`.

Comment: What input data did you use?

Comment: I've updated the snippet. You can check the result on a variety of data

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
 if (Json !=undefined && typeof Json.ID[0] != undefined ) {
        alert('validation message found');
    } else {
        alert('validation message not found');
    }
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

This error occurs when main json object is either empty or undefined. This happens when there is no data in json object.

Comment: Hi I have tried you example but every time I am getting alert('validation message found')

Comment: Please check revised answer.  You have to put && operator instead of ||

Comment: try to use undefined instead of 'undefined'