# How to check if a variable has been declared even if it hasn't been defined?

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined, undeclared-identifier

This question:

[JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized)

does not regard the case of variables which have been declared but not defined (as opposed to undeclared and undefined). Specifically, if I want to check whether `x` has been declared, this:

`typeof x == 'undefined'`

will not do, because...

```
var x; //<- declared but undefined
// idontexist  not declared

typeof idontexist === typeof x; // evaluates to true
```

This has implications: if variable has been declared it wont become a global variable, whereas if a variable has not declared, it would become a global variable, possibly leading to memory leak.

So how do I check in javascript if undefined variable has been declared?

Regarding the implications of this, consider this code:

```
function test() {

  var x
  console.log(typeof x == typeof y); // true
  if (typeof x == 'undefined') {
     x = 3;
  } 
  if (typeof y == 'undefined') {
     y = 5; 
  }
}
test();
y; // 5
x; // Reference Error
```

Comment: Global variables and memory leaks have very little to do with each other. That said, it's really unclear why you could possible need to know this. You tell whether a variable is declared by *looking at the source code*. Are you doing some kind of code generation?

Comment: With `try-catch`, I guess.

Comment: good to know, i dont use strict mode.

Comment: Agreed with @meagar, not sure what you're hoping for here - is there a real world example of this causing an issue? Memory leak is not an issue from this.

Comment: memory leak does happen and so will conflicts, but just to stay on topic.. how would i check if variable has been declared or not. I am not asking about memory leak

Comment: With ES6 you can use const variable so you can check and change this if not assign.

Comment: that only works for const since you have to define it right away. what about var and let

Comment: @meagar you have assigned this question as duplicate, answers there clearly use `typeof` and as i explained in the body of this question the very first thing that is not what i want

Comment: `window.hasOwnProperty('prop')` ?

Comment: An interesting question, but to all intents and purposes, this should be irrelevant at run-time. This seems like a job for an IDE rather than the code itself.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo i thought about that but what if you are inside a function

Comment: only solution that i know is to assign everything as null upon declaration. But it seems logical that there is a difference between a declared property and undeclared property so a way to check between them should exist.

Comment: At least one answer there explicitly addresses this issue.

Comment: Instead of checking `if (typeof x == 'undefined')` you can easily simplify this by just doing `x = x || 3`

Comment: What is the scenario for not knowing whether a variable is global or local? This is all known at compile time. It's not a runtime decision.

Comment: Simple way to find this in runtime is by using "use strict" directive in your JavaScript files. This will throw error if you have any undeclared variables.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to use an undeclared variable will throw a [ReferenceError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError), so you can use a `try catch` block to determine if a variable has been declared.

```js
var myVar;

try {
  myVar;
  console.log('myVar was declared.');
} catch(error) {
  if (error instanceof ReferenceError) {
     console.log('myVar was NOT declared');
  } else {
    console.log('Caught some other error.');
  }
}

try {
  notDeclared;
  console.log('notDeclared was declared');
} catch(error) {
  if (error instanceof ReferenceError) {
    console.log('notDeclared was NOT declared.');
   } else {
    console.log('Caught some other error.');
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had answered this several years ago..., can't remember where.

```
    "variablename" in this //> true : false
```

where ***this*** is any executional context which would otherwise have access to that variable name value.

```
    function exists( x ){ return x in this }
```

Comment: `in` is for object properties, not for variables. It might work for `var`-declarations in the global scope, but that's about it.

Comment: isn't global scope a window object?

Comment: @Umer jo muhamut. Not all scripts are run on Browser environment!