# A javascript 'let' global variable is not a property of 'window' unlike a global 'var'

Tags: javascript, var, let

I used to check if a global `var` has been defined with:

```
if (window['myvar']==null) ...
```

or

```
if (window.myvar==null) ...
```

It works with `var myvar`

Now that I am trying to switch to let, this does not work anymore.

```
var myvar='a';
console.log(window.myvar); // gives me a
let mylet='b';
console.log(window.mylet); // gives me undefined
```

Question:
With a global `let`, is there any place I can look if something has been defined like I could with `var` from the `window` object?

**More generally**:
Is `var myvar='a'` equivalent to `window.myvar='a'`?
I hear people say that at the global level, `let` and `var` are/behave the same, but this is not what I am seeing.

Comment: [`typeof`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/519157)

Comment: Clearly documented: *"At the top level of programs and functions, let, unlike var, does not create a property on the global object."* – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: You should never need to *test* whether a variable is declared or not, you should know it. And if you really want them to be global, don't use `let` at all - just assign to a property of `window`.

Comment: @Bergi yeah, I am going to go with assigning a prop to <code>window</code>.  The reason for testing if something is declared or not is: I have a library of utilities, and some have common dependency.  If a dependency is not yet loaded, I would then load it.

Comment: You should use a loader that remembers itself what it loaded and what not, so there's no need to dynamically test and synchronously (?) load anything.

Comment: Hmm, my loader is actually doing what you are describing, and I don't check is some var is declared anymore.  I guess I just feel uneasy not having the ability to check if something is declared.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> I hear people say that at the global level, let and var are/behave the
>   same, but this is not what I am seeing.

Eh, yes and no. To answer your question, in the large majority of cases `let` and `var` are the same when declared globally, but there are some differences.

To explain: A **global environment record** is where JS keeps all the logic and memory values for the code in play. However, this global environment record is really a composite encapsulating an **object environment record** and a **declarative environment record**.

Some more explanation:

A **declarative environment record** stores the bindings in an internal data structure. It's impossible to get a hold of that data structure in any way (think about function scope).

An **object environment record** uses an actual JS object as data structure. Every property of the object becomes a binding and vice versa. The global environment has an object environment record whose "binding object" is the global object. This would be the *Realm*, which in most cases is the `window` object.

So, per the ECMA spec, only *FunctionDeclarations*, *GeneratorDeclarations*, and *VariableStatements* create bindings in the **global** environment's object environment record.

All other declarations (i.e `const` and `let`) are stored in the global environment's **declarative** environment record, which is not based on the global object. They still declare a variable, but are not a *VariableStatement*.

**TL;DR: Both are still global, but `var`s are stored in the `window` object, while `let`s are stored in a declarative environment that you can't see (just like you can't access a variable in a function scope from outside of the function). When declared globally, both statements are pretty much identical in use.**

Comment: Wrong. According to spec:  **Declarative environment records** are used to define the effect of ECMAScript language syntactic elements such as `FunctionDeclarations`, `VariableDeclarations`. Declarative, not object.

Comment: A good code example would fit really well in this answer.

Comment: Thanks. do you have the source references for the concepts in your reply?

Comment: this is the stupidest most randomly unexpected sideffect of using const and let....