# How can I identify all client side global variables from the browser's developer console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When you go to any page, there is a lot of JavaScript data. Some of it is created by the browser for browser things, some is created by the page for page/client things.

How can I identify all of the data created by the page for the page/client things?

I can't just iterate the properties `window` because that will include everything.

For example:

- browser things

  - window.alert
  - window.onblur
  - window.screenY
  - window.document
- client things

  - window.$
  - window.nacho
  - window._blah

I want to go through all data created by or for the page, excluding all the internal things that the browser needs/has.

Comment: You can use a content script run before the document loads, e.g., `"run_at":"document_start"`, make a shallow copy of all global variables, then some time later log all global variables, compare.

Comment: @guest271314 I'm doing this from the developer console. So I can't interject code that would run before the document loads.

Comment: @jsejcksn No. In fact, that question asks for all globals where as I am only asking for ones that match my criteria.

Comment: The only way I can think of to do that, as I've done similar experiments and tests before, is to get the data before scripts load, then after scripts load. There's no guarantee that even more scripts might be assigned to the global scope after some user action or non-action, then be reverted.

Comment: Open a blank page, iterate `window`, use that result to determine which properties to exclude.

Comment: There's no difference between a "default" property and a "custom" property once they've been added - ie there's no "is this a custom property" property (meta-data on properties).

Comment: The "custom" properties are at the end of `Object.keys(window)` (usually) or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)` (also includes the non-enumerable props). To get a list of the standard props you can add an empty iframe to document.body and use `Object.keys(iframe.contentWindow)`

Comment: The nominated duplicates used to close this post are largely irrelevant . Global variables declared using `const` or `let` are held in environment records, not properties of the global object. Trying to find variables not declared using `var` is doomed before starting. The duplicates' answers may be applicable if the code has been transpiled to use `var` declarations instead of `const` and `let`.

Comment: To add to @traktor point, worth a general read: [Do let statements create properties on the global object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776079/do-let-statements-create-properties-on-the-global-object) and [let global variable is not a property of window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39414692/a-javascript-let-global-variable-is-not-a-property-of-window-unlike-a-global)