# How to check if variable is containg data or not in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 variable 'aassn' and 'addd' in xml format. my concern is if 'Idc' of 'aassn' is blank then dont need 'Idc' value in output and same if 'Idd' of 'addd' is blank then dont need in output. If, 'Idc' and 'Idd' contaning data then need both in output. where aassn=

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<info>
 <name>
  <Idc>81</Idc>
 </name>
</info>
```

and addd=

my code is

```
var ssn1 = aassn.match(/<Idc\/>/);
var acc1 = addd.match(/<Idd\/>/);
var tempaassn = String(aassn);
var tempacc = String(addd);
var star1 = "Hi,\n\nDetails";

if (typeof(ssn1) != 'undefined' && ssn1 != '' && String(ssn1) != '' && tempaassn.indexOf('</Idc>') > -1) 
star1+= "\n\nBelow first data:\n\n" +  aassn.split("<Idc>")[1].split( "</Idc>" )[0];

if (typeof(acc1) != 'undefined' && acc1 != '' && String(acc1) != '' && tempacc.indexOf('</Idd>') > -1) 
star1+= "\n\nBelow secound data\n\n" +  addd.split("<Idd>")[1].split( "</Idd>" )[0];

return star1;
```

But i am gettitng output as below while Idd of addd is blank:

```
 Hi,
 Details:
 Below first data:
 81
 Below secound data:
```

Comment: And your question or problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your question, but you could check the `length` property of a string to check if it contains something:

```
var data = "";

if(data.length > 0){
    // Evaluates to true.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof(myvariable) != 'undefined')
{
    // Variable is initialised i.e. data is set
}
```

Comment: I tried, but not working, var ssn1 = aassn.match(/<Idc\/>/);
var acc1 = addd.match(/<Idd\/>/);
var tempaassn = String(aassn);
var tempacc = String(addd);
var star1 = "Hi,\n\nDetails";

if (typeof(ssn1) != 'undefined' && ssn1 != '' && String(ssn1) != '' && tempaassn.indexOf('</Idc>') > -1) 
star1+= "\n\nBelow first data:\n\n" +  aassn.split("<Idc>")[1].split( "</Idc>" )[0];

if (typeof(acc1) != 'undefined' && acc1 != '' && String(acc1) != '' && tempacc.indexOf('</Idd>') > -1) 
star1+= "\n\nBelow secound data\n\n" +  addd.split("<Idd>")[1].split( "</Idd>" )[0];

return star1;

Comment: check if this helps .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized

Comment: not working, i am gettitng output as below when Iddd of addd is blank:  Hi,
 Details:
 Below first data:
 81
 Below secound data:     , but i need  Hi,
 Details:
 Below first data:
 81

Comment: please check the values of each variable in the conditions. does it help?