# I am trying to check if a variable exists using a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if a variable exists using a function but somehow this doesn't work, can somebody help me, thanks a lot!

```
// console returns false and is expected
if(typeof aaaaaaa !== 'undefined'){
  console.log(true);
}else{
  console.log(false);
}

=============================================

// console returns 'aaaaaaa is not defined', and stops my code
function checkExist(arg){
    if(typeof arg !== 'undefined'){
        console.log(true);
    }else{
        console.log(false);
    }
}
checkExist(aaaaaaa);
```

it's just different than [JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized)

Comment: could done better like this if(typeof aaaaaaa !== void(0)) or if(aaaaaaa !== void(0))

Comment: that is expected, as when you are calling checkExist(aaaaaaa) , it is trying to find the reference to aaaaa so it can be passed on to the method. Where as in the earlier case, you are just trying to read the type of a variable that doesn't exist and it works.

Comment: remove `aaaaaaa` from `checkExist(aaaaaaa);`

Comment: I would add "typeof aaaaaaa !== 'undefined' || aaaaaaa !== null" to make sure the null values aren't passed

Comment: Just use theObject.HasOwnProperty("aaaaaaa")

Comment: if(typeof (aaaaaaa) !== 'undefined') mind the () for 'typeof'

Comment: If you are in strict mode, it's completely correct that it stops your code, as you have a syntax error