# Best way to check if a variable exists in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, undefined

Well, my question is obvious,

Example:

Define `a` with default value `undefined`:

```
var a;
```

If I want to check if `a` var exists, I will try with:

But in this case, `a` does exists and `a` value is `undefined`, but in the `boolean evaluation` this is `false`.

```js
var a; // default value is 'undefined'
if (a) {
    alert('a exists');
} else {
    alert("a don't exists")
}
```

I can also try with the following example: but this example generates a error.

```js
// var a;
// a is not defined
if (a) {
    alert('a exists');
} else {
    alert("a don't exists")
}
```

And in this example, I try with `typeof`. But `a` is defined with `undefined` value by default.

```js
var a;
if (typeof a != 'undefined') {
    alert('a exists');
} else {
    alert("a don't exists")
}
```

And in this example

```js
console.log ('var a exists:', window.hasOwnProperty('a'));
```

What is the best way to verify if a variable actually exists and why?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized)

Comment: If by default variable a is undefined, then check (typeof a == "undefined").

Comment: For the first, `a === undefined`. For the second, use linters and watch your developer console so you can fix bugs where you forgot `var a`. Don't use unnecessary `typeof` hacks that hide useful error messages and allow bugs to go undetected.

Comment: @Dekel my question is about "best way" to check, no "how to". Sorry my bad english.

Comment: If you double check the content of the question there is "Which method of checking if a variable has been initialized is better/correct?", which is almost the same is "best way" :) (check all the answers there...)

Comment: To determine which approach is "best", we need to know [what you actually need this for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 4):

There are three different possibilities in JS for a variable.

1. Variable 'a' not at all declared;
2. Variable 'a' declared, but unassigned (undefined). Ex: `var a;`
3. Variable 'a' declared, but assigned with empty or null.  (Possible scenario, if a variable trying to get value from back-end)
   Ex:

   `var a=null; 
   var a='';`

If you are expecting a value in variable, other than 0 or false, then better to use following condition.  And of course its all based on your need and if you unsure about variable or object values, always enclose them in try & catch block.

```js
//var a;
//var a=null;
//var a='';
//var a=0;
//var a='value';

if (typeof a != "undefined" && a) {
  alert("a is defined AND a is TRUE value");
} else {
  alert("a not exist OR a is a FALSE value");
}
```