# Typescript - Declare optional global variable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I am creating a service to check if a user is logged in. This will just be a global variable 'userIsLoggedIn' which is passed from the backend. This service will be used across several applications and sometimes the userIsLoggedIn global variable will not exist.

What I have is...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare const userIsLoggedIn: boolean;

@Injectable()
export class UserLoggedInService{
    isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
        return userIsLoggedIn || false;
    }
}
```

If the userIsLoggedIn global variable does not exist then I get an error and if I leave out the declaration line then I get an error.

I had hoped to be able to do something like

```
declare const userIsLoggedIn?: boolean;
```

But this does not seem to work. Could anybody help me out please?

Comment: What's the error message you're getting if the variable doesn't exist? In any case, I think you should rather use the `typeof` operator to check for existence, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form me it worked if I made the check   `(typeof userIsLoggedIn !== 'undefined')` . Anything else that I have tried didn't worked. Your code now should look like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare let userIsLoggedIn: boolean;

@Injectable()
export class UserLoggedInService{
    isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
        if(typeof userIsLoggedIn !== 'undefined'){
            return userIsLoggedIn;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```