# How to declare a Global Variable in typescript

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, global-variables

I have inherited a Typescript project (has .ts) but I? can't seem to workout how to create a Global variable in a Typescript file and access it another.

I am new to Typescript so please bear with me.

I am not using Angular - saw this link  [Typescript - Declare optional global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929754/typescript-declare-optional-global-variable)

Any pointers highly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a global variable in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906359/create-a-global-variable-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which runtime you are using typescript (eg: nodejs or browser)

### NodeJS runtime

You have to `export` and `import` your variable.

```
// a.ts
export const foo = "bar";
```

```
// b.ts
import { foo } from 'a.ts';
```

### Browser runtime

You can use the global object `window`

```js
window.foo = "bar"
```

You can also use `export` and `import` but in this case you have to build your code with a builder (webpacker, rollup and so on)

Since typescript 3.4, you can also use `globalThis` on both runtimes:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#type-checking-for-globalthis