# What happens to a declared, uninitialized variable in Javascript? Does it have a value?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I can do

```
> var foo;
< undefined
> foo;
< undefined
```

This *suggests* that in Javascript, declared uninitialized variables are always *undefined*. But are they? Or could they, like in C, take on a random garbage value?

[MDN's var docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) weren't of help.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized/6509422?r=SearchResults&s=2|163.7775#6509422

Comment: Semi-related, since you look to be typing into the console: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54979906/is-there-any-difference-between-declared-and-defined-variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They won't take a random garbage value, if no value is assigned, it will stay "undefined".

That gives the possibility to check if an object as yet been assigned :
From [MDN](http://function%20test(t)%20%7B%20%20%20if%20(t%20===%20undefined)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20'Undefined%20value!';%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20return%20t;%20%7D%20%20var%20x;%20%20console.log(test(x));%20//%20expected%20output:) :

```
function test(t) {
  if (t === undefined) {
     return 'Undefined value!';
  }
  return t;
}

var x;

console.log(test(x));
// expected output: "Undefined value!
```

> A variable that has not been assigned a value is of type undefined. A
>   method or statement also returns undefined if the variable that is
>   being evaluated does not have an assigned value. A function returns
>   undefined if a value was not returned.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript any property that has not been assigned a value it is assigned as `undefined`. There are two things you need to seperate to understand it, there are two Undefined "things" from [ECMA-262 Standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/):

- 4.3.9 undefined value
- 4.3.10 Undefined type

`Undefined type` => type whose sole value is the undefined value

`undefined value`=> **primitive** value used when a variable has not been assigned a value

So in your case the variable is **initialized** and it has been **assigned** the `undefined` value.

Also a **premitive value** in javascript is defined as:

> **4.3.2 primitive value**
>
> member of one of the types Undefined, Null, Boolean,
>   Number, or String as defined in Clause 8
>
> NOTE: A primitive value is a datum that is represented directly at the
>   lowest level of the language implementation.