# Is there any difference between declared and defined variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I try writing the following lines in the console one by one

```
let x = y //throws error "Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined"
console.log(x) //throws error "ReferenceError: x is not defined"
let x = 3; //gives error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'x' has already been declared"
x = 3 //ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

Now problem is that how can be a variable **not defined** and **has been declared** at the same time. Is there any difference between both.

Comment: It's a poor use of language by the browser consoles. Those `ReferenceError`s should really say the variable is not "declared", but afaik it's always been thus.

Comment: From link: *When there's assignment, the right-hand side is parsed first; if the right-hand side throws an error, it never gets to the left-hand side, and the variable declared with let never gets properly initialized; it'll stay in the demilitarized zone / temporal dead zone forever* (and you can't re-declare a variable that's already been declared, even though the attempted assignment during initialization threw an error).

Comment: There's a big difference between **declaration** and **initialization**.
In your first line `x = y`, you declared `x`and tried to assign `y` to it, which is `undefined`, so `x`is declared and will be initialized with `undefined` as `value`. That's why you got `x` is already declared.

Comment: @cнŝdk but `console.log(x)` throws an error `x is not defined`

Comment: @ CertainPerformance Thanks. Your answer makes sense but if the variable is declared we should be able to assign it a new value but `x = 3` also throws error. Here there is not re-declaration

Comment: @MaheerAli `let x = 3;` will throw error as you have already declared it. But `x=3` should not throw error, unless you define it as `const`

Comment: @Rajesh But `x=3` is throwing error

Comment: Being declared doesn't mean it will be initialized to undefined. [Are variables declared with let or const not hoisted in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222689/3082296)

Comment: @CertainPerformance quick question on your explanation. `let x` on first line adds `x` to TDZ. Since `y` is not available, it throws error and assignment fails. Hence line 2 and 3 fails. But on line 4, `x=3` should do a proper assignment and it should remove `x` from TDZ. But that also fails. I fail to understand that

Comment: @Rajesh `x` is declared because of the hoisting but it's never initialized. From [Bergi's asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222689/3082296) "*The lexically declared variables however stay uninitialised. This means that a ReferenceError exception is thrown when you try to access it. It will only get initialised when the let/const/class statement is evaluated*" Since the line does that initializing it, throws an error here, `x` is in sort of a *limbo* where it's declared but unintialized. So, any type of assignment `x=3` will always thrown an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `let` or `const` variable can only be *declared* once - that is, when you have `let <variableName>` in a scope, you have declared `<variableName>` in that scope, and cannot declare it again in that scope.

From the [previously linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54231651/what-causes-the-different-behaviors-between-var-and-let-when-assign-them-a-r/54231786#54231786):

> When there's assignment, the right-hand side is parsed first; if the right-hand side throws an error, it never gets to the left-hand side, and the variable declared with let never gets properly initialized; it'll stay in the demilitarized zone / temporal dead zone forever

You can't re-declare a variable that's already been declared, even though the attempted assignment during initialization threw an error.

> But on line 4, x=3 should do a proper assignment and it should remove x from TDZ. But that also fails. I fail to understand that

After a variable has been *initialized* (for example, the `let x` runs), it can be assigned to. But just like you can't assign to a variable *before* its `let` initialization, you also can't assign to a variable later, when its initialization did not complete successfully:

```js
x = 'foo';
let x = 'bar';
```

Error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

Which is the same sort of thing that happens in the console when you try:

```
let x = y
// Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined
// x has not been initialized, so the next line throws:
x = 'foo'
// Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

`x` still has not been initialized, so the error is the same.

Encountering this sort of thing is *pretty odd*, though - you only see it in the console. In normal scripts, a thrown error will prevent further execution, and the fact that a variable name remains uninitialized forever is not something to worry about.

---

The above was an issue in earlier Chrome versions. But [in Chrome 80+](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/12/devtools), re-declarations of `let` are now permitted, so [the error](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/images/2019/12/letbefore.png)

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'x' has already been declared

should no longer occur, regardless of whether the previous initialization of the variable succeeded or not:

[image]

Comment: I'd like to point out that in Firefox's console `let x = y` does initialize `x` and `x = "foo"` doesn't throw. However doing the same [out of the console](https://jsfiddle.net/dpm0vu21/), it throws correctly.