# How to check SELECTED option is UNDEFINED or NOT in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to check in `if statement` whether the select option value is `undefined` or not.

I tried like below. But it doesn't take effect

```
if ($('#Combo_DocType').find(':selected').val() === "undefined") {
        $('#failspan').text('undefined');
    }
```

**For example:**

if the user doesn't select any one of the options from `ComboBox`, it will be remain `undefined`, So I want to alert them,

Comment: use `typeof` instead

Comment: Please add some code, the question itself is not self explanatory

Comment: try to use `undefined` not `"undefined"` coz the latter is a String and what you want to compare is the `undefined` value

Comment: You're currently checking whether it's equal to the string "undefined", if you're checking against the `undefined` state, use `typeof` as treyBake says. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: @DBS I never tried with `typeof`, Could you please tell me how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/519157/1650337

Comment: Are you trying to find a value explicitly set to the string `undefined`, or are you trying to check if anything has actually been selected? There's a better approach if you're trying  the latter.

Comment: @DBS ah, I shoulda tried actually looking instead of being lazy xD will rm my answer

Comment: though here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dhsfxy7o/

Comment: @DBS `typeof` is working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized)