# How to make sure the instance of an object is not declared twice in javascript

Tags: javascript

So here is the thing. Am creating an instance of an object `var newInstance = new MyObject()` on click of a button, but i want to make sure that when the button is clicked, it checks to see if that particular instance `newInstance` of that object `MyObject` has been created already, which if it has been created, prevent it from creating that instance again. I hope its clear enough.

This is what i have tried so far:

```
button.addEventListner("click", function(){
   if(newInstance instanceof MyObject){ // also tried newInstance instanceof Object
       return false; // this didn't work, i tried using preventDefault(); and to no avail
       // at this point i don't want the instance to be created anymore
   }
   else{
       var newInstance = new MyObject(); // create the instance
   }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized)

Comment: make `newInstance` global.

Comment: Keep newInstance as this.newInstance and use this same condition if `this.newInstance!=null` while creating obj.

Comment: Please could you guys back up your answers with the possible code. Thank You

Comment: You're declaring `var newInstance` inside the listener function so it won't be accessible outside (and shadow the possibly already existing variable). Your code is more or less fine if you fix that: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/wo8vmxy0/ Or use the Singleton pattern: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/wo8vmxy0/3/

Comment: i'll try it out and see...feedbacks coming soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the scope of the object. In your code the `newInstance` object is only available to that invocation of the function.
Next time it runs it doesn't know anything about the last newInstance.

If instance you make the scope of newInstance external to your function, then it works:

```
var newInstance = null;

button.addEventListner("click", function(){
   if(newInstance){ // also tried newInstance instanceof Object
       return false; // this didn't work, i tried using preventDefault(); and to no avail
       // at this point i don't want the instance to be created anymore
   }
   else{
       newInstance = new MyObject(); // create the instance
   }
});
```

If you dont want `newInstance` on the global scope then you could use `this.newInstance = ...` (as suggested by @Tejas) wrap the above in a closure:

```
(function(){
    //Code from above
})();
```

Comment: let me try both solutions and see....i'll be back with feedbacks

Comment: But one quick problem, if i use newInstance instanceof MyObject, it doesn't work, but if i use newInstance instanceof Object, it works? any idea why

Comment: You actually don't need either. Just `if (newInstance)` this is only truthy if set.