# How to check if google tag analysis is loaded before using it?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am new to google analytics tag, I am sending event on click, now I have added data-consent as you can see below my script tag in a header.

Tag

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>my app</title>


 <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async  type="text/plain" data-consent-category="3" src="gtagjs link"></script>
<script type="text/plain" data-consent-category="3">
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'my code');
</script>
```

Sending event to GTA

```
if(gtag){
    console.log('GTA IS LOADED');
    gtag('event', "take_test", {
        'event_category': "engagement",
        'event_label': labela,
    });
}else{
    console.log('NO GTA IS NOT LOADED');

}
```

When  I run my app I get the following

`gtag is not defined`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized)

Answer (score 0):

This is your current snippet:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async  type="text/plain" data-consent-category="3" src="gtagjs link"></script>
<script type="text/plain" data-consent-category="3">
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'my code');
</script>
```

I am sure that you replaced *gtagjs link* to hide the ID, however the `text/plain` type attribute is definitely wrong because the code doesn't recognize as JavaScript but as text. As a result it does not load the library and gives you the error `gtag is not defined`.

So, or you replace the snippet with the following (with your ID instead of you replaced):

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID');
</script>
```

or you have to use `text/plain` for the event too (if you want to block Analytics without consent):

```
<script type="text/plain">
    gtag('event', 'take_test', {
        'event_category': 'engagement',
        'event_label': labela,
    });
</script>
```