# JavaScript check for value including 0

Tags: javascript

In javascript I need to check for a value in an if statement if it exists. The thing is 0 can be one of the accepted values. so when I do

```
if(!val) {
   return true
}

return false
```

The thing is Javascript evaluates !0 = false

here are test cases what I want:

```
val = 0 // true
val = 91 // true
val = null // false
val = undefined = false
```

Basically check check for null but include 0. Not sure how to do this :/

Comment: What about `val != null`?

Comment: `(val === null || val === undefined)`

Comment: @DanielBeck is that the same as `!(val !== null)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized)

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, it isn't; null and undefined are not the same thing.  (I'm not certain which one the asker really cares about here, but they're not equivalent)

Comment: if(!val || val === 0){...}

Comment: @DanielBeck sorry I didn't mean to imply they are. `val != null` is only false for null and undefined

Comment: I see what you mean, @evolutionxbox -- you're right, that does work (it depends on one of those weird js non-strict equality edge cases though, they make me itchy :)

Answer (score 1):

`0` is falsy so `!0` is `true` in JavaScript, but to meet your test cases I think you want truthy values to return `true`, and you need to handle the special case for `0`. One way to do it:

```js
function test(val) {
  if (val || val === 0) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}

console.log(test(0));
console.log(test(91));
console.log(test(null));
console.log(test(undefined));
```

You could also leverage Javascript's weak equivalence operator and use `!= null` which covers `null` and `undefined` as below:

```js
function test(val) {
  if (val != null) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}

console.log(test(0));
console.log(test(91));
console.log(test(null));
console.log(test(undefined));
```

Answer (score 0):

For type check you have:

typeOf:
// note: typeof [] = object and typeof {} = object
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Array.isArray():
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

isNaN()/Number.isNaN():
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Is one of those what you're looking for?

```
!0 = true // in js. just tried it on MDN
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be checking for null & undefined in your conditional statement. That way, anything that is 0 or greater will return true. You also need to check the typeOf() for undefined because you undefined is not the value of the variable.

```
if (typeof(val) != 'undefined' && val != null && !(val < 0)){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for `undefined` and `null`:

```js
function isValNumber(val) {
  if (val === undefined || val === null) {
    return false
  }
  return true
}

console.log(isValNumber(0))
console.log(isValNumber(91))
console.log(isValNumber(null))
console.log(isValNumber(undefined))
```