# How Javascript let keyword prevents re-defining?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm python developer.
In python, When you want to check whether a variable is already defined, you use `dict`

```py
memo = {}
if 'a' not in memo:
    memo['a'] = 'var_a'
```

javascript let keyword has similar functionality, it prevents re-defining.

```
let a = 1;
let a = 2; // SyntaxError
```

So how `let` achieves this functionality under the hood? Does V8 engine keeps some kind of HashMap of let variables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized)

Comment: Yes, the JS engine does keep a list (or map or set) of the variables that are available in the current scope and where they are defined.

Comment: `dict`s in Python and variables in Python are different things. The JavaScript equivalent of that would be more like `let memo = new Map();` `if (!memo.has('a')) { memo.set('a', 'var_a'); }`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var

Comment: If you are interested in how this works in general, I recommend  reading https://craftinginterpreters.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does V8 engine keeps some kind of HashMap of let variables?

Essentially, yes - though it's not a V8 thing in particular, it's something that all spec-compliant JavaScript engines must adhere to. It's called an [environment record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-environment-records), which in this case is a "lexical environment", which is, to oversimplify, a collection of identifiers for a given scope and the values that the identifiers hold at that point.

When a function is evaluated, [FunctionDeclarationInstantiation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) runs, which does, among many other things:

```
34. For each element d of lexDeclarations, do
  a. (unimportant; omitted)
  b. For each element dn of the BoundNames of d, do
    i. If IsConstantDeclaration of d is true, then
      1. Perform ! lexEnv.CreateImmutableBinding(dn, true).
    ii. Else,
      1. Perform ! lexEnv.CreateMutableBinding(dn, false).
```

The `lexDeclarations` include identifiers declared with `let` or `const` inside the function. This list **cannot have duplicate entries** as a result of an [Early Errors](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-block-static-semantics-early-errors) requirement, which says, for blocks:

> It is a Syntax Error if the LexicallyDeclaredNames of StatementList contains any duplicate entries.

Identifiers declared with `var`s are slightly different - they're not LexicallyDeclaredNames, but VarDeclaredNames instead, which have no requirement against being listed multiple times in a block. This doesn't result in duplicate `var` names being created multiple times in the environment because the duplicate declarations are [explicitly skipped](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) from the `CreateMutableBinding` call:

```
e. For each element n of varNames, do
  i. If n is not an element of instantiatedVarNames, then
    1. Append n to instantiatedVarNames.
    2. Perform ! varEnv.CreateMutableBinding(n, false).
    ...
```

Comment: Is the environment record that is populated in *FunctionDeclarationInstantiatin* even relevant? The early error is thrown when the code is parsed, not when the function is called.

Comment: It shows how and where an identifier becomes associated with a value by the engine, which I think is useful given part of the question was *Does V8 engine keeps some kind of HashMap of let variables?*, even though that section isn't where the error would occur when a duplicate name is found