# Javascript - Undefined throws an exception so how can you test for it?

Tags: javascript

I have the below code:

```
    if (typeof profileChart !== undefined) {
        profileChart.destroy();
    } else {
        let profileChart = new Chart(
           pisteElevationProfileChart,
           configPiste
        );
    }
```

Despite the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized), I still get an error as follows;

`script.js?ver=1.0:336 Uncaught ReferenceError: profileChart is not defined`

So how can you test for an undefined variable.

Comment: `if (profileChart) {` should work

Comment: I tried that too, which should also check undefined, null, '', NaN, 0, false but still get the same error.

Comment: `typeof` returns a STRING ... so `typeof undefined !== undefined`

Comment: troubleshooting hint: `console.log(typeof profileChart)` before that code - what does it say it is

Comment: console.log('typeof profileChart: '+typeof profileChart) gives me:  typeof profileChart: undefined

Comment: **undefined** should be in **'undefined'** if (typeof profileChart !== 'undefined')

Comment: so there you have it, it's undefined ... so `if (typeof profileChart !== "undefined") {` should be correct ... note `"undefined"` not `undefined`

Comment: Yes, agree, doesn't work.

Comment: @JaromandaX   I wonder if you have a link where I may read more please.  Cannot use that code in script mode?  What is the alternative to script mode?

Comment: I was wrong I think - well, not QUITE right - mplungjan answer has it right

Comment: to be honest, the only problem was `undefined` not being `"undefined"` in your code - simple typo

Comment: Which engine and version are you getting this in? I'm not able to reproduce this as written. I only get the error with specifically `if (profileChart) {` when `profileChart` is undefined.

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://github.com/KooiInc/typeofAnything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others explained the typeof issue.

The reference error you get when you do `if (profileChart)` is because you need to DECLARE the variable before you can test it for falsy values.

```
let a;
if (a) // undefined
if (b) // referenceError
```

You declare it and wrap it like this

```js
let profileChart; // This will hold the current instance of the chart

const getProfileChart = (pisteElevationProfileChart, configPiste) => {
  // Destroy the existing chart if it exists
  profileChart?.destroy(); // optional chaining
  // Create a new chart and return it
  return new Chart(pisteElevationProfileChart, configPiste);
};

// before you want to use it

profileChart = getProfileChart(pisteElevationProfileChart, configPiste);
```

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan Can you please explain why if(profileChart) will not work? or a link to read more.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Because you need to DECLARE the variable. It is undefined when you do `let profileChart` but until then it is undeclared and you get a ReferenceError

Answer (score 1):

the issue is that the `typeof` operator returns a string representing the type of the operand so when checking if a variable is `undefined` you need to compare the result of `typeof` with the `string undefined`

```
if (typeof profileChart !== 'undefined') {
    profileChart.destroy();
} else {
    let profileChart = new Chart(
       pisteElevationProfileChart,
       configPiste
    );
}
```

best approach would be to declare `profileChart` with an initial value of undefined outside of your if/else block.

```
let profileChart;

// some other code where profileChart might be defined

if (profileChart !== undefined) {
    profileChart.destroy();
} else {
    profileChart = new Chart(
       pisteElevationProfileChart,
       configPiste
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
if (typeof profileChart !== undefined) {
```

The `typeof` value is never going to be `undefined`. You need to check against `typeof undefined`.

```
if (typeof profileChart !== typeof undefined) {
```

**Explanation:**

```
typeof profileChart
```

This piece of code will evaluate to the string `"undefined"` if the variable `profileChart` is not defined.

```
"undefined" !== undefined
```

This statement will always evaluate to `True`.

```
typeof undefined
```

will evaluate to "undefined".

```
"undefined" !== "undefined"
```

evaluates to `False` so the `else` block would be executed when the variable is not defined.

Comment: From my understanding if(profileChart) should check undefined, null, '', NaN, 0, false whereas if(typeof profileChart) will check undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be slightly deeper in the code. What is the line where you declare the variable and what keyword do you use (`var`, `let`, or `const`)? The scope where you are declaring the variable also matters. If, for example, you declare a variable inside an `if` statement (something like the following:

```js
if(statement) {
   const profileChart = //...;
}

if (typeof profileChart !== undefined) {
    profileChart.destroy();
}
//...
```

), then the variable will never be accessible (ReferenceError is the error where variable has not been initialized yet and so it can't be accessed for the type checking). The solution that can work here is:

```js
let profileChat;
if(statement) {
   profileChart = //...;
}

if (profileChart) {
    profileChart.destroy();
}
//...
```

Hope this is well, but it's better to rearrange this sort of code in favor of the const declaration